# Ignore row if returns null sql

Tags: mysql

I am using Alias.
Below is my query. I want to avoid showing rows with `NULL` counter.

```
SELECT activity_id, user_id,
(CASE WHEN activity_id = 1 OR activity_id = 2 THEN user_id END) AS counter 
FROM eventedge_ticket_activity
```

It gives the following result:

[image: SQL Result]

How can I skip rows with counter `NULL`?

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but below should work.

```
SELECT activity_id, user_id, 
CASE activity_id WHEN 1 THEN user_id 
                 WHEN 2 THEN user_id
                 ELSE NULL
END AS counter 
FROM eventedge_ticket_activity 
WHERE counter IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Don't think so counter won't be seen in where clause. Will work if where changed to having as long as only_full_group_by is not set.

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'counter' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0):

Below is the query which ran successfully.

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT activity_id, user_id, case when activity_id=1 then user_id when activity_id=2 then user_id end as counter FROM eventedge_ticket_activity) db where counter != 'NULL'`

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that the sample data is over simplified so I may be quite wrong but this looks like the same query parsing the data only once.

```
SELECT activity_id, user_id, 
 user_id AS counter 
FROM eventedge_ticket_activity 
WHERE activity_id in(1,2)
```

BTW the answer provided by marmeladze should also work with the change I mentioned in my comment

Answer (score 0):

Inner 'SELECT' gives table with NULL's, outer 'SELECT' cuts off rows with NULL counter

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT activity_id, user_id,
(CASE WHEN activity_id = 1 OR activity_id = 2 THEN user_id END) AS counter 
FROM eventedge_ticket_activity) AS ResultTable
WHERE ResultTable.counter IS NOT NULL
```